# express Router passing passport.jwt middleware

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I know I can pass passport.js as a middleware to express router with this structure:

```
router.post(
    '/users/update',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    UserController.updateOne
    );
```

but, I need to use blow structure for clarity and standardization and..... but I don't know how to pass passport middleware to my routes.is there any way I can pass passport to my new design?

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
require("./../../services/passport").passportAPI(passport);
const adminRouter = express.Router();

adminRouter
    .route("/roomfacilities")
    .get(RoomFacilities.getAll)
    .post(RoomFacilities.createOne);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#router.route)

You can do somthing like

```
adminRouter
  .route("/roomfacilities")
  .all(passport)
  .get(...)
```

Also [.use()](https://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#router.use) should work also.

```
adminRouter
  .use(passport)
  .route(...)
  .get(...)
```